# Error turning on PS4: "Cannot access system storage"

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

There are reports of PS4s not working out of the box with the following error:

> ### Safe Mode
>
> Cannot start the PS4.
>   Cannot access system storage.
>   Press the power button for 1 second (until the system beeps) to turn off the PS4.
>   (CE-34335-8)

Is there something I can try to fix this myself before returning the PS4 or sending it in to Sony?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Some PS4s appear to have shipped with a loose or improperly seated hard drive](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Consoles-Peripherals/INFO-Proper-Seating-of-PS4-Hard-Drive/m-p/42138109), possibly due to a missing screw.  Open the hard drive bay cover and make sure the hard drive is properly seated.  If the hard drive screw, marked with the four PlayStation button symbols, is missing, contact Sony for service. (Alternatively, a standard hard drive screw as supplied with most computer cases can be used to secure the hard drive.)

For more information on how to replace the hard drive, see [this article](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/Upgrade-PS4-HDD/).

*Side note: The missing screw may be the result of [deliberate sabotage at the Foxconn manufacturing plant](http://news.softpedia.com/news/PlayStation-4-Sabotaged-by-Foxconn-During-Manufacturing-Report-401003.shtml).*

Comment: Softpedia is probably the least legit "news source" I can think of

Comment: The sabotage might not really be happening: http://www.slashgear.com/playstation-4-foxconn-sabotage-rumors-continue-swirling-18305844/

Comment: Regardless of authenticity, I had not heard the rumour and found it interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I was missing my HDD screw. I just installed the HDD and used a standard screw from a old PC to hold it in. After that the system worked fine and updated quickly. No other noticeable problems since. The glossy cover slides off to reveal the HDD. Sony has made the HDD easy to change out and you don't have to void the warranty to check it. Hope this helps

Comment: This isn't really an answer, its more of a comment, indicating you had the same problem and DragonLord's answer was correct.